# What is the nature of the relationship between Maz Kanata and Chewbacca?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, star-wars-legends, the-rise-of-skywalker, chewbacca

[According to Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maz_Kanata#cite_note-Commander_Note-22), the mobile game *Star Wars: Commander* refers to Chewbacca as Maz Kanata's boyfriend.

Also, in the (canon) novel *[Star Wars: Force Collector](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_Collector)*, Maz Kanata says this about Chewie:

> "[...] a very handsome Wookiee who would never cheat me in such a fashion, nor would he allow it to occur if he'd been aware of it. We're very fond of one another, and he would not treat me so badly. Don't let anyone tell you different."
>
> <sub>*Star Wars: Force Collector*</sub>

Yet in *[The Star Wars Holiday Special](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Holiday_Special)*, we meet Chewie's wife Malla (and his son Lumpy).

Both the game and the special are set between *A New Hope* and *The Empire Strikes Back*. So what's the deal with Maz Kanata and Chewbacca? When and how did they meet, and what is their relationship? Especially given that in the films, they show no such signs of affection as common between lovers.

Comment: Maz certainly shows signs of affection to Chewie in the films, whether it's really returned or not is unclear.

Comment: it's my understanding that the holiday special is canon, but I think that everyone (including Disney) likes to pretend it isn't. Hence they don't mind the contradiction.

Comment: It seems to me the likeliest explanation is that either the mobile game creators didn't recognize Maz was joking, or the the Wookiepedia editor failed to realize the game was also joking.

Comment: Yeah, Speaking of George Lucas himself doesn't even like to acknowledge its existence. the only good thing we go out of that was the Boba Fett short.

Comment: Are you implying that Chewie slept with Maz only to get a medal?

Answer (score 6):

According to the Force Awakens [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html), Maz refers to Chewie as her boyfriend:

> **MAZ**: Where's my boyfriend?
>
> **HAN**: Chewie's working on the Falcon.
>
> **MAZ**: I like that Wookiee.

Whether that was true or only a joke, remains unclear as Maz has very little screen time in later films.

Comment: I understood that as a dis on Han; "Oh, it's you.  Where's someone I actually *like*?"

Comment: It could be, that's why I mentioned it might be a joke ;-)

Comment: Well, this doesn't add on a lot. What we need is an answer that tells us whether or not she was serious.